# Server to Client back to server synchronization

Tags: c#, wpf, microsoft-sync-framework

I am developing a **WPF** application that interacts with **localdb** using the **Entity Framework 6.0**

So the past couple of weeks I've been attempting to get synchronization setup between the following database types:

**Server:** SQL Server 2008 Database

**Client:** localdb (SQL Express)

While I can get the structure of the database from the server transferred onto the client it does not bring over the relationships.

This somehow changes the way the ADO.NET Entity Data Model is generated.
When the Entity Data Model is generated for the server structure it generates the many-to-one-to-many relationships as a collection (many-to-many), but on the localdb that is generated (with no relationships generated) it keeps the table structure. This causes issues with my application. I can't fully migrate to an offline application if the synchronization doesn't work properly.

**Server to Client (Initialization of client):**

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Synchronization;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer;

namespace DatabaseSetup
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                CreateLocalDatabase();
                ProvisionServer();
                ProvisionClient();
                Sync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception thrown: {ex.Source}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception thrown: {ex.Data}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception thrown: {ex.Message}");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        public static void CreateLocalDatabase()
        {
            var conn = new SqlConnection(LocalDb);
            var command = new SqlCommand(@"CREATE DATABASE ********", conn);

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine(command.ExecuteNonQuery() <= 0
                    ? @"Creating '********' Database on '(localdb)\v11.0'"
                    : @"Database '********' already exists. Attempting to synchronize.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    conn.Close();
            }
        }

        public static void ProvisionServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Attempting to provision server for synchronization...");
            // connect to server database
            var serverConnection = new SqlConnection(Server);

            // define a new scope named ProductsScope
            var scopeDescription = DatabaseScope(serverConnection);

            // create a server scope provisioning object based on the ProductScope
            var serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConnection, scopeDescription);
            if(!serverProvision.ScopeExists("DatabaseScope"))
            {             // skipping the creation of table since table already exists on server
                serverProvision.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);

                // start the provisioning process
                serverProvision.Apply();
                Console.WriteLine(@"Provisioning complete.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"Server already provisioned.");
            }
        }

        public static void ProvisionClient()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Attempting to provision client for synchronization...");
            // create a connection to the SyncExpressDB database
            var clientConnection = new SqlConnection(Client);

            // create a connection to the SyncDB server database
            var serverConnection = new SqlConnection(Server);

            // get the description of ProductsScope from the SyncDB server database
            var scopeDesc = DatabaseScope(serverConnection);

            // create server provisioning object based on the ProductsScope
            var clientProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConnection, scopeDesc);

            if (!clientProvision.ScopeExists("DatabaseScope"))
            {
                // starts the provisioning process
                clientProvision.Apply();
                Console.WriteLine(@"Provisioning complete.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"Client already provisioned.");
            }
        }

        public static void Sync()
        {
            //Define conections
            Console.WriteLine(@"Attempting to synchronize.");
            var serverConnection = new SqlConnection(Server);
            var clientConnection = new SqlConnection(Client);

            //Create Sync Orchestrator
            var syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator
            {
                Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.DownloadAndUpload,
                LocalProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("DatabaseScope", clientConnection),
                RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("DatabaseScope", serverConnection)
            };

            ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += Program_ApplyChangeFailed;

            var syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nSynchronization complete:");
            Console.WriteLine($"Start Time: {syncStats.SyncStartTime}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded: {syncStats.UploadChangesTotal}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded: {syncStats.DownloadChangesTotal}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Time Elapsed: {syncStats.SyncEndTime}");
            Console.Read();
        }

        private static DbSyncScopeDescription DatabaseScope(SqlConnection connection)
        {
            //Define scope
            var scopeTables = new Collection<DbSyncTableDescription>();

            foreach (var table in TableList)
            {
                scopeTables.Add(SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(table, connection));
            }

            var databaseScope = new DbSyncScopeDescription("DatabaseScope");

            foreach(var table in scopeTables)
            {
                databaseScope.Tables.Add(table);
            }

            return databaseScope;
        }

        static void Program_ApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            // display conflict type
            Console.WriteLine(e.Conflict.Type);

            // display error message 
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the action I setup to happen when the user clicks a button on the application whenever they want to sync:

**Synchronization between client and server:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Synchronization;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data;
using Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer;
using Outreach.Resources;

namespace WpfApplication
{
    class DatabaseSynchronization
    {
        public static void Sync()
        {
            //Define conections
            Console.WriteLine(@"Attempting to synchronize.");
            var clientConnection = new SqlConnection(Constants.Client);
            var serverConnection = new SqlConnection(Constants.Server);

            //Create Sync Orchestrator
            var syncOrchestrator = new SyncOrchestrator();
            syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("DatabaseScope", clientConnection);
            syncOrchestrator.RemoteProvider = new SqlSyncProvider("DatabaseScope", serverConnection);
            syncOrchestrator.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.UploadAndDownload;

            ((SqlSyncProvider)syncOrchestrator.LocalProvider).ApplyChangeFailed += Program_ApplyChangeFailed;

            var syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();

            Console.WriteLine("\n\nSynchronization complete:");
            Console.WriteLine($"Start Time: {syncStats.SyncStartTime}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded: {syncStats.UploadChangesTotal}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded: {syncStats.DownloadChangesTotal}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Time Elapsed: {syncStats.SyncEndTime}");
            Console.Read();
        }

        static void Program_ApplyChangeFailed(object sender, DbApplyChangeFailedEventArgs e)
        {
            // display conflict type
            Console.WriteLine(e.Conflict.Type);

            // display error message 
            Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
        }

        private static DbSyncScopeDescription DatabaseScope(SqlConnection connection)
        {
            //Define scope
            var scopeTables = new Collection<DbSyncTableDescription>();

            foreach(var table in Constants.MsoTableList)
            {
                scopeTables.Add(SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(table, connection));
            }

            var outreachScope = new DbSyncScopeDescription("DatabaseScope");

            foreach(var table in scopeTables)
            {
                outreachScope.Tables.Add(table);
            }

            return outreachScope;
        }

        public static void ProvisionServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Attempting to provision server for synchronization...");
            // connect to server database
            var serverConnection = new SqlConnection(Constants.Server);

            // define a new scope named ProductsScope
            var scopeDescription = DatabaseScope(serverConnection);

            // create a server scope provisioning object based on the ProductScope
            var serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConnection, scopeDescription);
            if(!serverProvision.ScopeExists("DatabaseScope"))
            {             // skipping the creation of table since table already exists on server
                serverProvision.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);

                // start the provisioning process
                serverProvision.Apply();
                Console.WriteLine(@"Provisioning complete.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"Server already provisioned.");
            }
        }

        public static void ProvisionClient()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(@"Attempting to provision client for synchronization...");
            // create a connection to the SyncExpressDB database
            var clientConnection = new SqlConnection(Constants.Client);

            // create a connection to the SyncDB server database
            var serverConnection = new SqlConnection(Constants.Server);

            // get the description of ProductsScope from the SyncDB server database
            var scopeDesc = DatabaseScope(serverConnection);

            // create server provisioning object based on the ProductsScope
            var clientProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConnection, scopeDesc);

            if(!clientProvision.ScopeExists("DatabaseScope"))
            {
                // starts the provisioning process
                clientProvision.Apply();
                Console.WriteLine(@"Provisioning complete.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"Client already provisioned.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Are there better options than Sync Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Sync Framework don't do schema syncs. it provisions the tables just so you sync data. If you want to include the full server schema, you'll have to script it yourself and execute on the client. if you're only after synching the FKs as well, you can include that as part of the db sync table description when you provision.

Comment: I am happy with just synching PK's and FK's. When you say FK's you're meaning the relationship information, right?